# Binding value with conditional

Tags: wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I'm binding a value to my DataGrid in WPF, and I would like to know how can I do something like this.

I have a int field (Category) into my model, and I would like to show a description string in my DataGrid.

Example:
The 'Category' field have this values 1,2,3,4,5 and each value has a description, how can I show the description and not the code in datagrid binding?

I've tried to create a method in my ViewModel and this method will return the string description.

```
//ViewModel 
public string GetDescription(int pCategory)
{
 if(pCategory == 1)
     return "01. Description";
 else if(pCategory == 2)
     return "02. Description";
 else if(pCategory == 3)
     return "03. Description";
 else
     return "None";
}

//XAML DataGrid binding code
<DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" Header="Category" Binding="{Binding GetDescription(Category)}"/>
```

Comment: There are multiple ways to do this. You can add another property to your view model, or you can use a Binding Converter, or a DataTrigger. It depends on where the description strings are supposed to be defined, in the view model or the view.

Comment: Wich is the best pratics to do this? Add a new property into my view model will not be a good thing, because I need to do this in a lot of classes and fields.

Comment: As said, it depends on where you need to define those strings. I don't think there's something like a general bast practice.

Comment: Okay! I'm gonna try Binding Converter! Thx

Answer (score 0):

In the view use a `DataGridTemplateColumn` and add data triggers, something like this

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox>
                <TextBox.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                        <Setter Property="Text" Value="None"/>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding pCategory}" Value="1">
                                <Setter Property="Text" Value="01. Description"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding pCategory}" Value="2">
                                <Setter Property="Text" Value="02. Description"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding pCategory}" Value="3">
                                <Setter Property="Text" Value="03. Description"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </TextBox.Style>
            </TextBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```